# Why is this nested for loop so much slower than unrolling the same code?

Tags: c, avr

I'm building a little toy console using the ATtiny85 and a 128x64px OLED. In my initial build I used the built-in `shiftOut()` and `digitalWrite()` functions to shift display data out to the screen controller.

This netted me ~5fps, which was a little disappointing.

I wrote my own function that uses direct port manipulation to send the data and got a dramatic increase in speed ~23fps, which is not bad. Here's that function:

```
void shift_out_block(block)
{
    byte b;
    for (byte i = 0; i < 8; i++)  
    {
        b = pgm_read_byte(block+i);

        for (byte j=0 ; j < 8 ; j++)
        {
            if ( !!( b & (1 << j)) )
            {
                PORTB |= 1 << SDA;
            }
            else
            {
                PORTB &= ~(1 << SDA);
            }

            PORTB |= 1 << SCL; // HIGH
            PORTB &= ~(1 << SCL); // LOW
        }
    }
}
```

23fps is ok, but it's no 30 or even 60fps (I'd actually have left it here if it was 24fps, but odd numbers...).

I understand why removing the library calls and manipulating ports directly improved things so much - the libraries are written to work on all sorts of different MCUs.

I vaguely remembered loop unravelling being a *thing*, so I unravelled the inner `for` loop:

```
void shift_out_block()
{
    byte b;
    for (byte i = 0; i < 8; i++)  
    {
        b = pgm_read_byte(block+i);

        if ( !!( b & (1 << 0)) )
        {
            PORTB |= 1 << SDA;
        }
        else
        {
            PORTB &= ~(1 << SDA);
        }

        PORTB |= 1 << SCL; // HIGH
        PORTB &= ~(1 << SCL); // LOW

        if ( !!( b & (1 << 1)) )
        {
            PORTB |= 1 << SDA;
        }
        else
        {
            PORTB &= ~(1 << SDA);
        }

        PORTB |= 1 << SCL; // HIGH
        PORTB &= ~(1 << SCL); // LOW

        if ( !!( b & (1 << 2)) )
        {
            PORTB |= 1 << SDA;
        }
        else
        {
            PORTB &= ~(1 << SDA);
        }

        PORTB |= 1 << SCL; // HIGH
        PORTB &= ~(1 << SCL); // LOW

        if ( !!( b & (1 << 3)) )
        {
            PORTB |= 1 << SDA;
        }
        else
        {
            PORTB &= ~(1 << SDA);
        }

        PORTB |= 1 << SCL; // HIGH
        PORTB &= ~(1 << SCL); // LOW

        if ( !!( b & (1 << 4)) )
        {
            PORTB |= 1 << SDA;
        }
        else
        {
            PORTB &= ~(1 << SDA);
        }

        PORTB |= 1 << SCL; // HIGH
        PORTB &= ~(1 << SCL); // LOW

        if ( !!( b & (1 << 5)) )
        {
            PORTB |= 1 << SDA;
        }
        else
        {
            PORTB &= ~(1 << SDA);
        }

        PORTB |= 1 << SCL; // HIGH
        PORTB &= ~(1 << SCL); // LOW

        if ( !!( b & (1 << 6)) )
        {
            PORTB |= 1 << SDA;
        }
        else
        {
            PORTB &= ~(1 << SDA);
        }

        PORTB |= 1 << SCL; // HIGH
        PORTB &= ~(1 << SCL); // LOW

        if ( !!( b & (1 << 7)) )
        {
            PORTB |= 1 << SDA;
        }
        else
        {
            PORTB &= ~(1 << SDA);
        }

        PORTB |= 1 << SCL; // HIGH
        PORTB &= ~(1 << SCL); // LOW
    }
}
```

No effort at all, copy-paste-7-times. Gives me nearly 75fps - the original function executes in ~42ms, the new **ugly** one takes only ~13ms.

Out of interest, I broke the *send bit* part out as a separate function and called that 8 times:

```
void shift_out_bit(bool bit)
{
    if ( bit )
    {
        PORTB |= 1 << SDA;
    }
    else
    {
        PORTB &= ~(1 << SDA);
    }

    PORTB |= 1 << SCL; // HIGH
    PORTB &= ~(1 << SCL); // LOW
}

void shift_out_block()
{
    byte b;
    for (byte i = 0; i < 8; i++)  
    {
        b = pgm_read_byte(block+i);

        shift_out_bit( !!( b & (1 << 0)) );
        shift_out_bit( !!( b & (1 << 1)) );
        shift_out_bit( !!( b & (1 << 2)) );
        shift_out_bit( !!( b & (1 << 3)) );
        shift_out_bit( !!( b & (1 << 4)) );
        shift_out_bit( !!( b & (1 << 5)) );
        shift_out_bit( !!( b & (1 << 6)) );
        shift_out_bit( !!( b & (1 << 7)) );
    }
}
```

~22ms to execute, or 45.4545454545 fps, which isn't even nearly a nice number.

I'm not a C programmer by any stretch of the imagination - Python is my usual haunt (I did initially start this project in Python/RPi, but *very* quickly gave up on that!).

Why is such a core language feature so much slower in this situation? As my project becomes more complex, what other optimisations should I be thinking about?

Comment: Sorry if you know this but, this looks like you are bit bashing I2C. The ATTiny85 has a hardware I2C.

Comment: Another perhaps useless comment is that you are testing if( !!( b & (1 << 0) ). You don't have to bother with the double NOT as if( b ) will be true if byte b is non-zero, doesn't have to be 1. The compiler may have already sorted this for you though so may be no speed increase.

Comment: @user1228123: That's cargo-cult coding (but should not harm here) in case the function takes an `int`, not a `bool`.

Comment: `void shift_out_block(block)` is not even a valid function header. You can't write good code if you don't know and understand the language.

Comment: I'm bit bashing SPI ;) and the double-!! got copied and pasted from somewhere else, I hadn't gotten around to what it actually *does* yet to see if I can simplify it!

Comment: Do you have compiler optimizations enabled?

Comment: Funny expression Olaf, hadn't heard it before. The !! inverts it twice and will have the effect of taking any non-zero byte to 1. SDA and SCL are normally associated with I2C. I guess your SDA is MOSI.

Comment: Oh, of course, I used SDA because that's what's silkscreened on the OLED board - it's one of those SSD1306 things can can use a whole bunch of different protocols, but came set as SPI!

Comment: I'm using the Arduino IDE, I'm not sure what optimisations that uses by default.

Comment: This sort of question can be very hard to answer as the speed can be so dependent on the compiler optimisations. An example is the function calls likely result in slower RAM based memory usage whereas the single function unravelled approach may just use registers. I don't know for sure though as have no idea what your toolchain is.

Comment: Side note: Come on, at 2k rep you're supposed to know that unless you @ping people they might not get notifications unless it's under their own post. :)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I earned my 2k rep a long time ago when there were fewer features and far fewer rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the "payload" operations done inside of your innermost loop:

- Check of a specific bit in `b`
- Conditional jump to deal with `PORTB |= 1 << SDA` vs. `PORTB &= ~(1 << SDA)`
- Three operations on `PORTB`

That is all the unrolled version of the loop does; nothing else needs to be done, not even shifting `1` to the left `j` times, because the compiler evaluates constant expressions, and `1 << 4` becomes simply `16`.

On the other hand, the loop without unrolling must do additional things to keep looping:

- Incrementing `j`
- Comparing `j` to 8
- Shifting `1` left by `j` positions
- Unconditional jump to the beginning of the loop

When the loop is unrolled, the CPU is no longer burdened with these "non-payload" instructions, so the execution speed goes up.

> Why is such a core language feature so much slower in this situation?

Many modern compilers would unroll loops automatically for you, depending on the optimization settings.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. I've made many "blinking lights" level programs, this is the most complex I've tried with C and I'm not used to the close-to-the-metal-ness ;) thank you